How to play mono (or very unbalanced stereo) through both ears?
I'm watching a lecture on YouTube that only plays sound through my left ear. I found the balance controls in System Settings, but if I move the slider all the way to the right, the video is silent. So it seems the video might be stereo with sound only in the left channel.
Is there a way to mix the audio to play through both ears equally? Or to play only the left channel through both ears? Note that this is a YouTube video that I do not control and cannot download.

I found it. System Settings > Accessibility > Audio > Play stereo audio as mono


THANK YOU. I've had this problem for years, never realized there was a solution until now!
